# Dax/powerquery retrieve last date with a country based on restriction

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a data set containing:
Accounts selling various fruits in various countries, im working on some metrics and I really want to calculate the time between the first sold fruit in a country to the last sold fruit in the same country.

For instance: "days between" First sold ORANGE in Austria to Last sold ORANGE in AUSTRIA

I have solved this using a measure, which works but this doesn't allow me to work further with it as it throws me error with circular dependicies (ALL reference!)

I wonder if I can do this less complicated? an idea would be to set up an additional table in powerquery having latest date sold by fruit and country similar to what a pivot can do in excel, after that I could link to my main table and retrieve the date by using the RELATED option.

Any ideas?

Current muesure in powerBI:

```
DURATION = 
VAR dispdate =
    MIN( 'Test dat'[Dispath] )
VAR lastsoldthiscountry =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( 'Test dat'[Last sold date] ),
        ALL( 'Test dat' ),
        SUMMARIZE( 'Test dat', 'Test dat'[Fruit], 'Test dat'[Country] )
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        NOT ( ISBLANK( lastsoldthiscountry ) ) && NOT ( ISBLANK(dispdate) ),
        INT( lastsoldthiscountry - dispdate )
    )
```

Excel raw test:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/cppyzagm4ahusrxmadlg6/Test_data_withPivot.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=2nf5wzl7etwr2hqg2lh4oyifx

PBI file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljnyics6d7n74oc/test.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do what you want entirely in Power Query.

- Group by `Fruit` and `Country`
- Aggregate by `Min` of `Start Date` and `Max` of `End Date`
- Add column to calculate the Days difference:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Fruit", type text}, {"Account ID", type text}, {"Country", type text}, 
        {"Sold amount", Int64.Type}, {"Dispath", type date}, {"First sold date", type date}, {"Last sold date", type date}}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Fruit", "Country"}, {
        {"First Date Sold", each List.Min([First sold date]), type nullable date}, 
        {"Last Date Sold", each List.Max([Last sold date]), type nullable date}}),
    
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Fruit", Order.Ascending}, {"Country", Order.Ascending}}),
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Days Sold", each 
        Duration.Days([Last Date Sold]-[First Date Sold]),Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]
*The negative number for France Apples seems due to a data entry error*
*If there is a missing date entry, the table will show a null, due to how PQ processes nulls in arithmetical operations*

Comment: Hi Ron. It looks promising, but maybe I'm doing this wrong. Can I add this in as custom column in powerquery? and get the days sold?

Comment: @Aabo That is the last step in the code. `#"Added Custom"`

Comment: I was trying this many times, then I realized what you did with the GROUPED ROWS.. which was exactly what I needed. I have now made a perfect small table and made a merge query!
THANKS